# FCM token keeps changing after killing the application and reopen it

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase notifications works in my Flutter app, but when I kill the app and reopen it the FCM token changes.
As I know the token won't change unless the user deletes the app but in my case, the notification was not received because the token is changed.
What is the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried with the different device?

Comment: this happened in my IOS physical device

Comment: please try once with other android/iOS device

Comment: in android, it is not changing,

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this behavior with this sample? https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-flutter/tree/main/messaging

Comment: I have the same issue, but not on all devices. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @user12125591 yes this happened only in ios devices, I'm facing the same issue till now :/

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any solution found? @TabarekGhassan

Answer (score 0):

The FCM token changes when the app is reinstalled or the data is cleared. To receive notifications even after the app is reinstalled or data is cleared, you should store the token on the server and use it to send notifications. Additionally, you can also retrieve the latest token when the app is launched and send it to the server, so that the server has the most recent token to send notifications to.

Comment: I didn't uninstall the app or delete data when terminated the app and the token automatically changed :/

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your AppDelegate file:

```
override  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] tokenWithCompletion:^(NSString *token, NSError *error) {
      if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error getting FCM registration token: %@", error);
      } else {
        NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", token);
//        self.fcmRegTokenMessage.text = token;
          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"fcm_token"];

      }
    }];
    return YES;
}
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken {
    NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", fcmToken);
    // Notify about received token.
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fcmToken forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:
     @"FCMToken" object:nil userInfo:dataDict];
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}

- (void)registerForRemoteNotifications {
     UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
     [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge |     UNAuthorizationOptionCarPlay) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
         if(!error){
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
             });
         }else{
             NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
         }
     }];
}
```